# How to extract data from an Array looking JSON in BigQuery

Tags: arrays, json, google-bigquery

I am trying to extract data from the variable metric_data that looks like an Array but it's a JSON.
This is an example:

```
[{"segmentName":"control","values":[[1588636800000.0,101],[1588723200000.0,546],[1588809600000.0,1195],[1591056000000.0,129]]},{"segmentName":"experiment","values":[[1588636800000.0,91],[1588723200000.0,680],[1588809600000.0,1214],[1588896000000.0,1269],.0,290],[1589760000000.0,248],[1589846400000.0,173],[1589932800000.0,167],[1590019200000.0,178],[1590105600000.0,131],[1590192000000.0,110]]}]
```

I am specifically trying to sum up the second part of the sub-arrays associated with the key "value" so that I have a row for each segmentName and sum of its values.  I only got as far as transforming into an array.

```
SELECT  
  array(select 
    x
    FROM UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(metric_data, '$')) x
  ) extracted
FROM temp
```

Comment: can you make the metric_data available as text?  its very hard to make use of a picture as source

Comment: `SELECT  segmentname, sum(values) from
  (select x.*
    FROM UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(metric_data, '$')) x ) group by 1`

Comment: Just added the variable as text

Comment: based on presented sample data  - please provide expected output!

Answer (score 0):

Based from my understanding you would like to get the sum for each **"segmentName"**. Two possibilities could be to sum everything (both array elements) or get the sum per element. But if my understanding is wrong please let me know so I can edit/delete my answer.

You can consider the queries below illustrating these two possibilities:

**Sum of values**

```sql
with sample_data as (
 select '[{"segmentName":"control","values":[[1588636800000.0,101],[1588723200000.0,546],[1588809600000.0,1195],[1591056000000.0,129]]},{"segmentName":"experiment","values":[[1588636800000.0,91],[1588723200000.0,680],[1588809600000.0,1214],[1588896000000.0,1269],[1588896000000.0,290],[1589760000000.0,248],[1589846400000.0,173],[1589932800000.0,167],[1590019200000.0,178],[1590105600000.0,131],[1590192000000.0,110]]}]' as json_string

)
-- Sum all values
select 
json_query(js,'$.segmentName') as segment_name,
sum(cast(arr_val as NUMERIC)) as sum_of_values
from sample_data
,unnest(json_query_array(json_string, '$')) js
,unnest(json_query_array(js,'$.values')) val
,unnest(json_query_array(val,'$')) arr_val
group by 1
```

Sum of values output:

[image]

---

**Sum per element of values**

```sql
with sample_data as (
 select '[{"segmentName":"control","values":[[1588636800000.0,101],[1588723200000.0,546],[1588809600000.0,1195],[1591056000000.0,129]]},{"segmentName":"experiment","values":[[1588636800000.0,91],[1588723200000.0,680],[1588809600000.0,1214],[1588896000000.0,1269],[1588896000000.0,290],[1589760000000.0,248],[1589846400000.0,173],[1589932800000.0,167],[1590019200000.0,178],[1590105600000.0,131],[1590192000000.0,110]]}]' as json_string
)
,cte as (
select 
  json_query(js,'$.segmentName') as segment_name,
  split(regexp_extract(val,r'\[(\d+\.?\d+?,\d+)\]'),',') as new_value
from sample_data
,unnest(json_query_array(json_string, '$')) js
,unnest(json_query_array(js,'$.values')) val
)
select 
  segment_name,
  sum(cast(new_value[offset(0)] as numeric)) as elem1,
  sum(cast(new_value[offset(1)] as numeric)) as elem2
from cte
group by segment_name
```

Sum per element of values output:

[image]

NOTE: Your JSON string is missing some brackets and values, hence I created a dummy value.